# Tracking notes CRM Dynamics 365 Sales

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Can you display all notes for all transactions in one view?
I can't find how to do it in standard ways. In essence "activities" there is no activity type "notes"
[image]

Comment: Can you explain little more?

Comment: In the "Actions" section, I can see all actions for possible deals except "Notes". Can they be brought there somehow? Screen added above

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you wanted to show OOB Notes entity in that Activity Type dropdown (Email, Fax, etc with checkboxes) - so that you can filter them in below grid.

Unfortunately, Notes is not an Activity - it cannot be included there. Moreover Notes is like a blob storage container where you can add annotation and attachments to any entity including Activities.

That filter dropdown can only include the available OOB activity types and the custom activity types.

[image]